# "Craft CMS does not support backtracking to this version. Please upload Craft CMS 0 or later."

Tags: database, error-message, manual-updates

I have a problem related [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12649/my-website-isnt-working-craft-does-not-support-backtracking-to-this-version) and [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14993/craft-files-and-db-out-of-sync) question. I began updating a long time ago (2017?) and got the error "Craft CMS does not support backtracking to this version. Please upload Craft CMS 0 or later" when I try to access the site or admin. I'm just now trying to fix it. I have tried replacing the app folder with a clean craft 2 version and I'm getting a blank white screen on everything.

I run a local install and a live install from the same DB.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I hadn't fully uploaded the app folder when I tried to access it earlier. Tried again, made sure it was finished before renaming and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error and used an older dump. I was, later on, able to access the admin panel.